# Use data from one textfield to populate other textfields in drupal 7 form

Tags: forms, ajax

I am new to drupal. I have a drupal form having fields Customer Name, Address and Phone. Is it possible to populate Name and Address Field automatically from database when the phone number is entered?

I am using Drupal 7.

Please help me and treat me as a beginner. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field)

> Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. T**hese computed
>   fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code**. You
>   may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the
>   current user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :)
>   ) You can also choose whether to store your computed field values in
>   the database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on
>   the fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

OR

You can do it by using `hook_form_alter` then define `copy_field_value.js` create behavior:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.moduleNameCopyFieldValue = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Repeat this for all fields as needed
      $('#source', context).on('blur', function () { 
        // above you can use change instead of blur if element is not changed by another js
        if (!$('#destination').val() || 0 === $('#destination').val().length) {
          $('#destination').val($(this).val());
          // wrap line above in "if no value" like I did, or other condition you like
        }
      });
      // end of "repeat this"
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```